# Im built a docker file for selenide java testing but all the e2e test are not running and only the api test are wroking

Tags: java, docker, selenide, e2e

when I'm trying to run only e2e in the docker its says 0 tests.
I believe the problem is in the chrome and chrome driver installation in the docker file.
I tried many things but noting had worked and I'm getting no errors.

```
FROM openjdk:21-ea-21-jdk-slim AS BUILD

# Set the working directory in the container
WORKDIR /app

# Copy the Maven configuration file (pom.xml) to the container
COPY pom.xml .

# Copy the source code into the container
COPY . .

# Build your application with Maven
#RUN apk add --no-cache maven && mvn clean package
RUN apt-get update && \
     apt-get install -y maven && \
     apt-get clean;

RUN apt-get update -y && apt-get install -y wget xvfb unzip jq
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y curl

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y chromium


# Install Google Chrome dependencies
RUN apt-get install -y libxss1 libappindicator1 libgconf-2-4 \
    fonts-liberation libasound2 libnspr4 libnss3 libx11-xcb1 libxtst6 lsb-release xdg-utils \
    libgbm1 libnss3 libatk-bridge2.0-0 libgtk-3-0 libx11-xcb1 libxcb-dri3-0


# Fetch the latest version numbers and URLs for Chrome and ChromeDriver
RUN curl -s https://googlechromelabs.github.io/chrome-for-testing/last-known-good-versions-with-downloads.json > /tmp/versions.json

RUN CHROME_URL=$(jq -r '.channels.Stable.downloads.chrome[] | select(.platform=="linux64") | .url' /tmp/versions.json) && \
    wget -q --continue -O /tmp/chrome-linux64.zip $CHROME_URL && \
    unzip /tmp/chrome-linux64.zip -d /opt/chrome

RUN chmod +x /opt/chrome/chrome-linux64/chrome


RUN CHROMEDRIVER_URL=$(jq -r '.channels.Stable.downloads.chromedriver[] | select(.platform=="linux64") | .url' /tmp/versions.json) && \
    wget -q --continue -O /tmp/chromedriver-linux64.zip $CHROMEDRIVER_URL && \
    unzip /tmp/chromedriver-linux64.zip -d /opt/chromedriver && \
    chmod +x /opt/chromedriver/chromedriver-linux64/chromedriver

# Set up Chromedriver Environment variables
ENV CHROMEDRIVER_DIR /opt/chromedriver
ENV PATH $CHROMEDRIVER_DIR:$PATH

ENV MAVEN_HOME /usr/share/maven
ENV MAVEN_CONFIG "$USER_HOME_DIR/.m2"

# Run the application when the container starts
CMD ["mvn", "test"]
```

```
INFO] 
2024-03-17T19:56:38.573205002Z [INFO] -------------------------------------------------------
2024-03-17T19:56:38.573276927Z [INFO]  T E S T S
2024-03-17T19:56:38.573561943Z [INFO] -------------------------------------------------------
2024-03-17T19:56:39.635558976Z [INFO] Running TestSuite
2024-03-17T19:56:59.738518367Z [TestNG-tests-1] INFO framework.cleanup.CleanupThread - Thread started
2024-03-17T19:57:02.483653897Z [INFO] Tests run: 0, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 22.82 s -- in TestSuite
2024-03-17T19:57:02.820011928Z [INFO] 
2024-03-17T19:57:02.820063444Z [INFO] Results:
2024-03-17T19:57:02.820072141Z [INFO] 
2024-03-17T19:57:02.821374723Z [INFO] Tests run: 0, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0
2024-03-17T19:57:02.821432691Z [INFO] 
2024-03-17T19:57:02.825335558Z [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
2024-03-17T19:57:02.825405780Z [INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
2024-03-17T19:57:02.826307320Z [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
2024-03-17T19:57:02.827949419Z [INFO] Total time:  02:25 min
2024-03-17T19:57:02.828526872Z [INFO] Finished at: 2024-03-17T19:57:02Z
2024-03-17T19:57:02.829058800Z [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

```
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.2.5</version>
                <dependencies>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.apache.maven.surefire</groupId>
                        <artifactId>surefire-testng</artifactId>
                        <version>3.1.2</version>
                    </dependency>
                </dependencies>
                <configuration>
                    <!-- Create report even if there are test failures -->
                    <testFailureIgnore>true</testFailureIgnore>
                    <argLine>
                        --enable-preview -javaagent:"${settings.localRepository}/org/aspectj/aspectjweaver/${aspectj.version}/aspectjweaver-${aspectj.version}.jar"
                    </argLine>
                    <suiteXmlFiles>
                        <suiteXmlFile>src/test/resources/SuiteCollection.xml</suiteXmlFile>
                    </suiteXmlFiles>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
```

I tried to use different installation in docker but noting has solved the problem.
only the api tests are running but not the e2e tests.

Answer (score 1):

If names of your e2e test classes end with `IT` (f.e. `MyTestCaseIT.java`) then `mvn test` should not execute it by default. You need to use `mvn verify` instead.

Comment: My test classes are not ending with IT. When I run mvn test locally its works. I am using maven surefire plugin to run xml file with all the tests.

Comment: Hi @PureSoul, can you then share your `pom.xml` or at least the surfire plugin configuration excerpt

Comment: I added surfire plugin configuration. I dont think there is a problem with the plugin because when I run the src/test/resources/SuiteCollection.xml the api tests are working.